# Jquery Accordion first panel auto opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

Can i set first panel on Jquery automatically opened?
My accordion panel is close all.

This is my html

```
<div class="accordionx">
<div class="acitemx">
    <h3>First Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
        This is the content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="acitemx">
    <h3>Second Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
        This is the content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="acitemx">
    <h3>Third Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx">
        This is the content
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS script

```
$(".acitemx h3").click(function () {
$header = $(this);
$content = $header.next();
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
});
```

});

This the JSFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/bupd32rq/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels that opened were added with `current` class, then put class `current` manually on first panel and respective div with `style="display:block"`:

```
<div class="acitemx current">
    <h3>First Panel</h3>
    <div class="accx" style="display:block">
        This is the content
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ja9gdmvd/)**

Comment: Thanks bro. But, the panel can be loop with php soon. Can you give the solution focus to edit the js not html?

Comment: Yeah, use this `$('.acitemx').eq(0).addClass('.acitemx').find('.accx').css('display','block');`

Comment: Great! Many Thanks bro :)

Comment: Hi Ghazali, How to close all panel when one of the panel opened? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

you can just add `.eq(0).click()`

```
$(".acitemx h3").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
    });
}).eq(0).click();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bupd32rq/2/)